Blazor web assembly does not render a new page after navigating to it
I have a Blazor wasm project with pre-rendering disabled.
When I open the site on a computer, everything works fine. On mobile devices, I get a blank page when I navigate.
I don't know where the problem is, so I'll show the code where it's probably problematic:
<Router AppAssembly="typeof(Program).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">

        @if (navigationManager.Uri.Contains("/market"))
        {
            <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="typeof(Layouts.MarketLayout)" />
        }
        else if (navigationManager.Uri.Contains("/user"))
        {
            <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="typeof(Layouts.UserLayout)" />
        }
        else if (navigationManager.Uri.Contains("/admin"))
        {
            <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="typeof(Layouts.AdminLayout)" />
        }
        else
        {
            <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="typeof(Layouts.AppMainLayout)" />
        }

        <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="routeData" Selector="h1" />
    </Found>

    <NotFound>

    </NotFound>

</Router>

Three asynchronous tasks are started in the main layout:
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    await searchEngine.Initialize();
    await purchasesManager.SyncPurchases();
    await purchasesManager.SyncPurchases();
}

If you clear the cache, everything works on the mobile device at first startup. Then after rebooting, everything crashes again.
I tried explicitly calling StateHasChanged after updating navigationManager.LocationChanged. No results

The problem was with the web.js library. I changed the app.razor rendering mode to InteractiveWebAssemblyRenderMode(prerender:false)
Changing
<script src=“_framework/blazor.web.js”></script>
to
<script src=“_framework/blazor.webassembly.js”></script> 
helped me solve the problem.
Screenshot

If it works in normal mode I don't understand why it doesn't work on  mobile.
Another way of doing this is using composition in the project structure and _Imports.razor.
Create folders for each layout type and add a _Imports.razor to the folder.  Set the layout in _Imports.razor:
@layout AdminLayout

Any Razor page within this folder will use AdminLayout, unless you set it directly in the Razor page.
I used a mobile emulation to test it.
Here's my test setup.

